Toggle bug, moving diagonally instead of straight
I'm working on a toggle, this is my code:
import style from "./Toggle.module.scss";

export default function Toggle() {
    return (
        <>
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" className={style.toggle} />
            <label htmlFor="toggle" className={style.label} />
        </>
    );
}


.toggle {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.label {
    width:60px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius:30px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
    left:10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    
    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 23px;
        height: 23px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background-color: green;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        transition: 0.3s;
        
    }
}

.toggle:checked ~ .label::after{
    
    transform: translateX(32px);
    


}

initially the knob is perfectly centered inside the switch, but when i click it, it makes a diagonal movement instead of moving in a straight line to the right.  See codesandbox for details.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/red-microservice-gq48pj?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

You need to add the translateY: (-50%) to the toggled transformation as well if you don't that value will not be added to the transformation:
.toggle {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.label {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  left: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: relative;

  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
}

.toggle:checked ~ .label::after {
  transform: translateX(32px) translateY(-50%);
}


One solution is:
&::after {
  ...
  top: 4px
  transform: translateX(0);
  ...
}

.toggle:checked ~ .label::after {
  transform: translateX(28px);
}

notice the translateX from translateY, since you're moving horizontally you don't need to set the Y axis at all.

Is there a way to vertically center it without top:4px? I feel like it's eyeballing it, i want a certain way to make sure its perfectly centered

one possible solution:
&::after, height: 80%; and top: 10% and it will scale when you change the height of the .toggle
